Required baseline optimization is not supported: VFPV3
I am currently attempting to download OpenCv onto my Raspberry Pi 4b, and I am following this tutorial text and when I attempt to download the last set of packages using Cmake I run into a couple errors. I have gone through my CMakeLists.txt and could not find the cause, I have also tried everything that the few other people with this problem have tried. The command I am running is below, along with the error message I got:
XXXX@raspberrypi:~/opencv/build $ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -D CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS=-latomic -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ..

-- Detected processor: aarch64
-- Looking for ccache - not found
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptimizations.cmake:607 (message):
  Required baseline optimization is not supported: VFPV3
  (CPU_BASELINE_REQUIRE=NEON;VFPV3)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptions.cmake:335 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:679 (include)


compiler too old?

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17429

Before the cmake command that gave you the error message, try to uninstall any apt installed opencv package, typing sudo apt purge libopencv-dev, on a terminal.
